# Questions about using JavaScript and event handlers in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

When you are using events in your HTML, and you include a small bit of JavaScript, what is that called? Is it called a "JavaScript attribute function", just a "JavaScript attribute", or what? ex:

```
<button onClick="location.href='some_place'">click me</button>
```

When using events, and you use the `return` keyword, what is that called? Is there some specific piece of terminology that is used to describe this? I am aware of what it does and how it works, I just do not know what to call it. ex:

```
<button onClick="return someFunction();">click me</button>
```

Can these two pieces of JavaScript be combined into one in this attribute? I would like to combine my first two examples into one. When the button is clicked, I want to call a JavaScript function. If the function returns "true", I want the location.href to fire. If the function returns "false", I do not want the location.href to fire.

Comment: nice question. im also curious to see the answer. for the specific first example, you can also just use the `a` tag in practice! (Sorry I don't have the answer to your questions though)

Comment: You could maybe use a ternary operator:
`<button onclick="someFunction()?location.href='some_place'">click me</button>`

It changes pages if the function returns true, otherwise nothing happens.
Obviously the function has to be declared beforehand

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is the event Handler 
   `return` is the return statement once the function reaches the return statement it will stop executing

combining the two function may look like this

```
function  someFunction(){
  var x = someBool; 
  if(x){
     location.href='some_place'
   }else{
     return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Usually, returns are assigned with the equals sign, like "some_return_var = someFunction();" This return just looks like it is hanging out all by itself.

Comment: Also, I figured the JavaScript would be similarly named to CSS. I figured the one used in the markup would be called an "Inline JavaScript", or something to that effect.

Comment: yes it is inline JavaScript of course However the onClick attribute is the element event handler

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is a HTML Attribute that binds an event to the element. The value of the attribute is the body of the event handler. You can write anything you want there, but you're limited by the fact that you need to escape quotes `"` in your code, otherwise the HTML parser will think that you've finished defining the attribute value.

So your code can be:

```
<button onclick="if(someFunction()) location.href='some_place';"></button>
```

but, like Sam Creamer pointed out, you don't need a button for it. You can do it with an `a href`:

```
<a href="some_place" onclick="return someFunction();"></a>
```

if `someFunction` returns false, the click event will be canceled, and you won't be redirected anywhere.

If you want more code in the attribute, a more practical way is to do this:

```
onclick="return someOtherFunction()"
```

, where someOtherFunction contains all your code.
Or like this JS code:

```
document.getElementById("the_id_of_the_element").onclick=function() {/* your code here */};
```

, however this might not work on older browsers (other code is necessary):

```
function bindEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if(element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent('on'+type, handler);
    }
}
bindEvent(document.getElementById("the_id_of_the_element"), 'click', function() {/*Your code here*/ });
```

You can also use jQuery to bind events, which does exactly the same

```
$("#the_id_of_the_element").on("click", function() {/*your code here*/});
$("#the_id_of_the_element").on("click", function() {/*some other code*/});
//both will execute
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inline JavaScript, bound to an event.
2. Same, but explicitly returning a value, like any other JavaScript function can. Here it may affect behavior, e.g., stopping normal event processing if the function returns false.
3. Just write the location value in the function you're calling.

#3 is a little tricky, though, because a function that doesn't *explicitly* return a value is returning `undefined`, which, depending on context, may not be a reasonable thing to do. In this case you might want to explicitly return `true` to keep things clear.

Comment: I would prefer to not put the location value into the called function as that would mean passing in a very big string. I'm using this within a PHP application and have onclick="location.href='./newPage.php?<?php echo $queryString; ?>"', where $queryString is pretty long.

Comment: @Brian You asked how to combine the two. The other option is to put it all in the inline JS, which is not a preferred solution. Note that I never said to pass the location string into the function, though. I'm not sure what the length of a string passed to a function has to do with anything, though.

Comment: In reality, the length of the string has nothing to do with it. I just always get nervous when I shuffle data back and forth like that.

Comment: @Brian Why? Most programming is about shuffling data around and/or transforming/filtering/etc it.

Comment: I don't know, I'm weird like that. It's probably because I'm passing it in as a parameter. I'm more used to working with Java and passing around object references, which are much smaller than a long string.

Comment: @Brian ... What do you think is happening when you pass an immediate string in Java? In php?

Comment: I'm not really up to speed on what happens behind the scenes with an HTML to JavaScript parameter. Is JavaScript pass by value or reference?